# PHP: можно ли вызывать сортировку usort() функцией / методом?

Tags: php, массивы

Собственно вот код:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($order)    { ... много кода ... });
```

Проблема в том, что данный код встречается несколько раз на странице, сортировка абсолютно одинаковая, просто вставляются разные переменные $array и $order. Есть ли возможность записать эту сортировку в функцию или метод класса, чтобы потом просто вызывать обработку в нужном месте, а не плодить большое количество одинакового кода?

Comment: ...Ответ: можно!

Answer (score 3):

Можно записать функцию сортировки в переменную и подставлять в `usort()` вместо анонимной функции эту переменную:

```php
$array1 = [
    'a',
    'c',
    'b',
];

$array2 = [
    'а',
    'в',
    'б',
];

$sortFunction = function ($a, $b) {
    return $a <=> $b;
};

usort($array1, $sortFunction);

print_r($array1);

usort($array2, $sortFunction);

print_r($array2);
```

- https://replit.com/@w3lifer/ViolentAnotherRobodoc#main.php
- https://php.net/ru/functions.anonymous#example-181

Answer (score 0):

Неудобство здесь может представлять пробрасывание значения `use ($order)` в функцию. Например, если этот вызов `usort` необходим в разных методах классах, где, конечно, $order будут свои собственные в каждом из них и из-за этого нет одного удобного места, где можно объявить анонимную функцию с `use`.

Но ничто не мешает сделать так:

```
function sortFunction($a, $b, $order) 
{
// ... много кода ...
}

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    return sortFunction($a, $b, $order);
});
```

Вместо функции здесь можно, разумеется, так же объявить и вызвать метод класса.